Finite group schemes that are not finite groups
I am trying to understand how far from finite groups are finite group schemes over $Spec(k)$, where $k$ is an arbitrary field of characteristic zero.
In order to help develop my intuition, I would appreciate seeing a buch of examples. So please write down below your favourite example of a finite group schemes as above that is not a finite group!

Just for your convenience, see this post for another question on finite group schemes.

Finite (abelian) group schemes over $k$ are automatically etale as you are in characterstic $0$, so they are the same thing as finite abelian groups with a continuous action of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$.

@AlexYoucis Ahhh is that true even without the abelianness condition? If so my question becomes really silly :/

@JeCl I think yes, assuming you set it up correctly (now it's a group acting by group morphisms).

By Cartier's theorem, finite group schemes over a field $K$ of characteristic zero are etale. So as Alex says in the comments the category of such things is equivalent to the category of finite groups equipped with a continuous action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$, by combining

The fact that the category of finite group schemes over an algebraically closed field $\overline{K}$ of characteristic zero is equivalent to the category of finite groups, via the functor sending a finite group to the corresponding constant group scheme, and
Either Galois descent or Grothendieck's Galois theory.

A nice explicit example is
$$\mu_n(A) = \{ a \in A : a^n = 1 \} \cong \text{Spec } K[x]/(x^n - 1)$$
which corresponds to $\mu_n(K^s) \cong C_n$ together with its Galois action by the cyclotomic character. And of course you can more generally just write down your favorite finite group $G$, then find some Galois extension of $K$ with Galois group acting nontrivially on $G$.

In case that makes a difference and so that I am sure I understand: Here by finite group you REALLY mean finite group? Or are you already viewing them as schemes?

@JeCl: I really mean finite group. The category of finite groups embeds into the category of finite group schemes over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, via taking the constant group scheme, and this embedding is an equivalence of categories. Then one gets the above statement using Galois descent, or Grothendieck's Galois theory.

@JeCl: after thinking about it maybe the easiest way to do this is to talk about finite sets first. So you can show in a very direct way that the category of finite sets is equivalent to the category of finite etale schemes over an algebraically closed field $K$ (of any characteristic); the equivalence sends a finite set $X$ to $\text{Spec } K^X$. Grothendieck's Galois theory tells you more generally that the category of finite etale schemes over $K$ is equivalent to the category of finite sets equipped with a continuous action of $\text{Gal}(K^s/K)$. Then you can take group objects...

...to conclude that the category of finite etale group schemes over any field $K$ is equivalent to the category of finite groups equipped with a continuous action of $\text{Gal}(K^s/K)$. Then you can apply Cartier's theorem if $K$ has characteristic zero.

@JeCl Just an advertisement for caution: as Qiaochu says, you can apply Galois descent, but Galois descent is delicate in general, but fine for affine things. If $G$ is a finite group with an action of the Galois group $\Gamma=\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ then you get an induced action on the constant group scheme $\underline{G}{\overline{K}}:=\mathrm{Spec}\left(A{\overline{K}}\right)$ where $A_{\overline{K}}=\prod_{g\in G}\overline{K}$. Explicitly, this comes from the action of $\Gamma$ on $A_{\overline{K}}$ obtained by acting $\overline{K}$-linearly and permuting the coordinates.

Your finite étale group scheme over $K$ is then given by $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, where $A=A_{\overline{K}}^\Gamma$. I leave it for you to work through the details that this is a finite étale $K$-scheme. The fact that it's a group scheme comes from observing that the comultiplication map $A_{\overline{K}}\otimes_{\overline{K}}A_{\overline{K}}\to A_{\overline{K}}$ (coming from the group structure on the coordinate labels of $A_{\overline{K}}$) induces a comultiplication map $A\otimes_K A\to A$ by passing to $\Gamma$-invariants.

@JeCl Oops, the above "...obtained by acting $\overline{K}$-linearly..." should be "...obtained by acting $\overline{K}$-seminlinearly..." (i.e., $\gamma(a_g):=(\gamma(a_{\gamma^{-1}(g)}))$.

@QiaochuYuan I know you probably know this, but you can't really apply any of the things you linked to explicitly as $\mathrm{Spec}(\overline{K})\to \mathrm{Spec}(K)$ is only pro-Galois -- you need continuity, and it's even then quite subtle -- in fact I think arbitrary Galois descent fails without assumptions like quasi-projective. The issue is that all varieties don't form a stack.

@Alex: really? I admit I haven't worked through this in as much detail as I'd like to but I was under the impression that everything should be fine for finite flat schemes?

@QiaochuYuan what is the precise statement? It is true that affine (or much more difficult: quasi-affine) morphisms form a stack for any reasonable toplogy. So finite flat morphisms (as finite and flat are both local for any reasonable toplogy and are are a subprestack of affine morphisms) are a stack. I'm just saying that the prestack of ALL locally of finite type schemes is not a stack. In fact not even quasi-projective schemes for most topologies richer than Zariski is a stack.
